# Failure on kubernetes cluster creation with kops

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I am trying to create a very simple cluster on aws with kops with one master and 2 worker nodes. But after creating, kops validate cluster complains that cluster is not healthy.

cluster created with:

```
kops create cluster --name=mycluster --zones=ap-south-1a --master-size="t2.micro" --node-size="t2.micro" --node-count="2" --cloud aws --ssh-public-key="~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
```

```
Output from kops validate cluster:

VALIDATION ERRORS
KIND    NAME                                                                                    MESSAGE
Pod     kube-system/kops-controller-xxxtk                                                       system-node-critical pod "kops-controller-xxxtk" is not ready (kops-controller)
Pod     kube-system/kube-controller-manager-ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal        system-cluster-critical pod "kube-controller-manager-ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal" is not ready (kube-controller-manager)

Validation Failed

Validation failed: cluster not yet healthy
```

Getting the resources in kube-system namespace shows:

```
NAME                                                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/dns-controller-8d8889c4b-rwnkd                                         1/1     Running            0          47m
pod/etcd-manager-events-ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx..ap-south-1.compute.internal       1/1     Running            0          72m
pod/etcd-manager-main-ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal         1/1     Running            0          72m
pod/kops-controller-xxxtk                                                  1/1     Running            11         70m
pod/kube-apiserver-ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal            2/2     Running            1          72m
pod/kube-controller-manager-ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   15         72m
pod/kube-dns-696cb84c7-qzqf2                                               3/3     Running            0          16h
pod/kube-dns-696cb84c7-tt7ng                                               3/3     Running            0          16h
pod/kube-dns-autoscaler-55f8f75459-7jbjb                                   1/1     Running            0          16h
pod/kube-proxy-ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal                1/1     Running            0          16h
pod/kube-proxy-ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal                1/1     Running            0          72m
pod/kube-proxy-ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal                1/1     Running            0          16h
pod/kube-scheduler-ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal            1/1     Running            15         72m

NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
service/kube-dns   ClusterIP   100.64.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   16h

NAME                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                                                      AGE
daemonset.apps/kops-controller   1         1         1       1            1           kops.k8s.io/kops-controller-pki=,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=   16h

NAME                                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/dns-controller        1/1     1            1           16h
deployment.apps/kube-dns              2/2     2            2           16h
deployment.apps/kube-dns-autoscaler   1/1     1            1           16h

NAME                                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/dns-controller-8d8889c4b         1         1         1       16h
replicaset.apps/kube-dns-696cb84c7               2         2         2       16h
replicaset.apps/kube-dns-autoscaler-55f8f75459   1         1         1       16h
```

Getting the logs from the kube-scheduler shows:

```
I0211 04:26:45.546427       1 flags.go:59] FLAG: --vmodule=""
I0211 04:26:45.546442       1 flags.go:59] FLAG: --write-config-to=""
I0211 04:26:46.306497       1 serving.go:331] Generated self-signed cert in-memory
W0211 04:26:47.736258       1 authentication.go:368] failed to read in-cluster kubeconfig for delegated authentication: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory
W0211 04:26:47.765649       1 authentication.go:265] No authentication-kubeconfig provided in order to lookup client-ca-file in configmap/extension-apiserver-authentication in kube-system, so client certificate authentication won't work.
W0211 04:26:47.783852       1 authentication.go:289] No authentication-kubeconfig provided in order to lookup requestheader-client-ca-file in configmap/extension-apiserver-authentication in kube-system, so request-header client certificate authentication won't work.
W0211 04:26:47.798838       1 authorization.go:187] failed to read in-cluster kubeconfig for delegated authorization: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory
W0211 04:26:47.831825       1 authorization.go:156] No authorization-kubeconfig provided, so SubjectAccessReview of authorization tokens won't work.
I0211 04:26:55.344064       1 factory.go:210] Creating scheduler from algorithm provider 'DefaultProvider'
I0211 04:26:55.370766       1 registry.go:173] Registering SelectorSpread plugin
I0211 04:26:55.370802       1 registry.go:173] Registering SelectorSpread plugin
I0211 04:26:55.504324       1 server.go:146] Starting Kubernetes Scheduler version v1.19.7
W0211 04:26:55.607516       1 authorization.go:47] Authorization is disabled
W0211 04:26:55.607537       1 authentication.go:40] Authentication is disabled
I0211 04:26:55.618714       1 deprecated_insecure_serving.go:51] Serving healthz insecurely on [::]:10251
I0211 04:26:55.741863       1 tlsconfig.go:200] loaded serving cert ["Generated self signed cert"]: "localhost@1613017606" [serving] validServingFor=[127.0.0.1,localhost,localhost] issuer="localhost-ca@1613017605" (2021-02-11 03:26:45 +0000 UTC to 2022-02-11 03:26:45 +0000 UTC (now=2021-02-11 04:26:55.741788572 +0000 UTC))
I0211 04:26:55.746888       1 named_certificates.go:53] loaded SNI cert [0/"self-signed loopback"]: "apiserver-loopback-client@1613017607" [serving] validServingFor=[apiserver-loopback-client] issuer="apiserver-loopback-client-ca@1613017607" (2021-02-11 03:26:46 +0000 UTC to 2022-02-11 03:26:46 +0000 UTC (now=2021-02-11 04:26:55.7468713 +0000 UTC))
I0211 04:26:55.757881       1 tlsconfig.go:240] Starting DynamicServingCertificateController
I0211 04:26:55.771581       1 secure_serving.go:197] Serving securely on [::]:10259
I0211 04:26:55.793134       1 reflector.go:207] Starting reflector *v1.StorageClass (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134
I0211 04:26:55.815641       1 reflector.go:207] Starting reflector *v1.CSINode (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134
I0211 04:26:55.841309       1 reflector.go:207] Starting reflector *v1beta1.PodDisruptionBudget (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134
I0211 04:26:55.857460       1 reflector.go:207] Starting reflector *v1.Pod (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134
I0211 04:26:55.875096       1 reflector.go:207] Starting reflector *v1.Node (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134
I0211 04:26:55.894283       1 reflector.go:207] Starting reflector *v1.Service (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134
I0211 04:26:55.894615       1 reflector.go:207] Starting reflector *v1.PersistentVolume (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134
I0211 04:26:55.895000       1 reflector.go:207] Starting reflector *v1.ReplicationController (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134
I0211 04:26:55.895250       1 reflector.go:207] Starting reflector *v1.ReplicaSet (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134
I0211 04:26:55.902323       1 reflector.go:207] Starting reflector *v1.StatefulSet (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134
I0211 04:26:55.902572       1 reflector.go:207] Starting reflector *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim (0s) from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134
I0211 04:26:55.905927       1 reflector.go:207] Starting reflector *v1.Pod (0s) from k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kube-scheduler/app/server.go:188
I0211 04:26:56.355570       1 node_tree.go:86] Added node "ip-172-20-43-190.ap-south-1.compute.internal" in group "ap-south-1:\x00:ap-south-1a" to NodeTree
I0211 04:26:56.357441       1 node_tree.go:86] Added node "ip-172-20-63-116.ap-south-1.compute.internal" in group "ap-south-1:\x00:ap-south-1a" to NodeTree
I0211 04:26:56.357578       1 node_tree.go:86] Added node "ip-172-20-60-103.ap-south-1.compute.internal" in group "ap-south-1:\x00:ap-south-1a" to NodeTree
I0211 04:26:56.377402       1 leaderelection.go:243] attempting to acquire leader lease  kube-system/kube-scheduler...
I0211 04:27:12.368681       1 leaderelection.go:253] successfully acquired lease kube-system/kube-scheduler
I0211 04:27:12.436915       1 scheduler.go:597] "Successfully bound pod to node" pod="default/nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-w4hb5" node="ip-172-20-63-116.ap-south-1.compute.internal" evaluatedNodes=3 feasibleNodes=2
I0211 04:27:12.451792       1 scheduler.go:597] "Successfully bound pod to node" pod="default/nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-4xz8l" node="ip-172-20-43-190.ap-south-1.compute.internal" evaluatedNodes=3 feasibleNodes=2
E0211 04:32:20.487059       1 leaderelection.go:325] error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-scheduler: Get "https://127.0.0.1/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-system/leases/kube-scheduler?timeout=10s": context deadline exceeded
I0211 04:32:20.633059       1 leaderelection.go:278] failed to renew lease kube-system/kube-scheduler: timed out waiting for the condition
F0211 04:32:20.673521       1 server.go:199] leaderelection lost
goroutine 1 [running]:
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2.stacks(0xc0005c2d01, 0xc000900800, 0x41, 0x1fd)
        /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:996 +0xb9
....
... stack trace from go runtime
```

Comment: have you tried other zones and regions,  not `ap-south`?

Comment: @Vitalii No, I haven't. Let me try and see if it works in other regions. But I don't think it has anything to do with region. Most likely it seems the issue is with the instance types that I have chosen and there is only one master node that I created. I will try in other regions too and get back with results.

Comment: I tried with master node type as t2.medium and it is not failing to validate like earlier. Possibly t2.micro is too small a instance to be running master node. I have seen in many places people using t2.micro for making a small cluster, so I am still not sure why only I am seeing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, after @Markus and your comments i started to dig deeper with an information and this is what I found.

First [Running Kubernetes on AWS T2 Instances](https://www.mobilise.cloud/running-kubernetes-on-aws-t2-instances/) article. Example of using T2.medium with very detailed steps and timeline describing what was going on there.

Conclusion in the end:

> We’ve shown that the **unpredictable nature of deployments** on Kubernetes
> clusters **isn’t a good fit for the T2/3 family of instances**. There is
> the potential to have instances throttled due to pods consuming vast
> amounts of resources. At best this will limit the performance of your
> applications and **at worst could cause the cluster to fail (if using
> T2/3s for master nodes) due to ETCD issues.** Furthermore, this
> condition will only be picked up if we are monitoring CloudWatch
> carefully or performing application performance monitoring on the
> pods.
>
> To this end it is advisable to avoid using T2/3 instance type families
> for Kubernetes deployments, if you would like to save money whilst
> using more traditional instance families (such as Ms and Rs) then take
> a look at our blog on spot instances.

And next to official info:

**1) t2.micro spec:** T2.micro is 1 vCPU and 1 gb mem
[t2.micro specs](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/):
[image]

**2) Minimal required memory & CPU (cores) for Kubernetes in general:**

- **Master node’s minimal required memory is 2GB** and the worker node needs minimum is 1GB
- **The master node needs at least 1.5** and the worker node need at least 0.7 **cores**.

Not enough resources. Please use minimum T2.medium for masters

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I came to the same conclusion. I got misled by various blogs / tutorials and even professional k8s courses which all seem to use t2.micro instances for creating cluster with kops for demo purpose. I was failing to bring up even a demo cluster with t2.micro instances. I sort of guessed it too but I really wanted to see where in the logs does it say it is failing due to insufficient resources. The logs were too much and for someone who is starting off his / her journey on k8s might get put off if even in logs one cannot reason out for the failure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything particularly wrong with the command you are running. However, t2.micro are very small, and may be too small for the cluster to function.

You can have a look at the kops-operator logs why it is not starting. Try `kubectl logs kops-controller-xxxx` and `kubectl describe pod kops-controller-xxx`

Comment: Markus. I was hoping for testing cluster I don't need to provision medium instances but may be your are right. Let me check the logs as well as try provisioning with slightly larger node sizes.

Comment: Here is the link to the logs: https://pastebin.com/e6L4k5eJ. I can't comprehend what is happening here. Just wondering if it has got something to with networking setup with kops?

Comment: markus I tried with master node type as t2.medium and it is not failing to validate like earlier. Possibly t2.micro is too small a instance to be running master node. I have seen in many places people using t2.micro for making a small cluster, so I am still not sure why only I am seeing this error